# Installation of Python and openssl --- without yum

Tags: python, linux, makefile, openssl

trying to install OpenSSL for python 3.8.3 in Linux,
make give the following error

I have added all the path required in .bashrc and .bash_profile
I have used /config comand

'''
./configure --prefix=$Home/.local/python --with-openssl=$HOME/.local/ssl
'''

```
Makefile:1884: warning: overriding commands for target `Modules/_ssl.o'
Makefile:1882: warning: ignoring old commands for target `Modules/_ssl.o'
Makefile:1885: warning: overriding commands for target `Modules/_ssl.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
Makefile:1883: warning: ignoring old commands for target `Modules/_ssl.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall    -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration  -I./Include/internal  -I. -I./Include    -DPy_BUILD_CORE_BUILTIN  -DUSE_SSL -IOME/.local/openssl1/include -IOME/.local/openssl1/include/openssl -c ./Modules/_ssl.c -o Modules/_ssl.o
./Modules/_ssl.c: In function ‘_ssl_configure_hostname’:
./Modules/_ssl.c:891: error: implicit declaration of function ‘SSL_get0_param’
./Modules/_ssl.c:891: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
./Modules/_ssl.c:893: error: implicit declaration of function ‘X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set1_host’
./Modules/_ssl.c:899: error: implicit declaration of function ‘X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set1_ip’
./Modules/_ssl.c: In function ‘_ssl__SSLContext_impl’:
./Modules/_ssl.c:3130: error: ‘X509_CHECK_FLAG_NO_PARTIAL_WILDCARDS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
./Modules/_ssl.c:3130: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
./Modules/_ssl.c:3130: error: for each function it appears in.)
./Modules/_ssl.c:3240: error: implicit declaration of function ‘SSL_CTX_get0_param’
./Modules/_ssl.c:3240: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
./Modules/_ssl.c:3246: error: implicit declaration of function ‘X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set_hostflags’
./Modules/_ssl.c: In function ‘get_verify_flags’:
./Modules/_ssl.c:3555: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
./Modules/_ssl.c: In function ‘set_verify_flags’:
./Modules/_ssl.c:3568: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
./Modules/_ssl.c: In function ‘set_host_flags’:
./Modules/_ssl.c:3764: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

Comment: Are you trying to compile Python 3.8.3 and OpenSSL at the same time? I believe if you just run `./configure` in the python source directory it will pickup your system ssl. The errors you're seeing suggest the openssl in `$HOME/.local/ssl` is either broken or incomplete.

Comment: It seems extremely unlikely that you actually used the specific `configure` command you say you did.  You will get better answers, faster, if you present such details accurately.  In particular, code and commands should generally be cut & pasted, not retyped, because retyping very frequently introduces errors.

Answer (score 0):

This `make` output ...

> ```
> gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall    -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration  -I./Include/internal  -I. -I./Include    -DPy_BUILD_CORE_BUILTIN  -DUSE_SSL -IOME/.local/openssl1/include -IOME/.local/openssl1/include/openssl -c ./Modules/_ssl.c -o Modules/_ssl.o
> ```

... suggests that your `configure` command was *not* ...

> ```
> ./configure --prefix=$Home/.local/python --with-openssl=$HOME/.local/ssl
> ```

In particular, I am looking at these bits of the output:

> ```
> -IOME/.local/openssl1/include -IOME/.local/openssl1/include/openssl
> ```

.  That's showing the effect of the text `$HOME/.local/openssl1` being expanded by `make` to `OME/.local/openssl1` (because no variable `H` is defined).  That, in turn, indicates that `$HOME` was not expanded by the shell when you ran `configure`, so it must have been quoted in the actual command you ran.  Something like this, maybe:

(wrong:)

```
./configure --prefix='$Home/.local/python' --with-openssl='$HOME/.local/openssl1'
```

Additionally, `$Home` is not the same as `$HOME`, so probably what you really want is:

(better:)

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/.local/python --with-openssl=$HOME/.local/openssl1
```

If you do quote then do it with double quotes ("), not single-quotes ('), because the latter suppress shell parameter expansion.  If there's anything in your home directory name that requires quoting, however, such as spaces, then you can expect other issues to arise, whether you quote in the `configure` command or not.